# How to hide components until data are bound in Lightning?

Tags: javascript, bestpractice, lightning-aura-components

What is the best way to configure components or elements to be hidden until the required data binding operations have been completed in the background via Ajax? I'd like to replicate the current behavior in S1, where a user logging in and opening the Feed tab sees a spinning "loading" icon until the Chatter feed is ready to be displayed.

Comment: Nothing special here for Lightning. You'll just draw the spinning loading icon, make the request, and replace the spinner with the newly generated component from the request response.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, you would first set the spinner to visible, pull down the information and then disable the spinner after populating the data. In a component that would look something like this.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FooCtrl" >
    <aura:attribute name="articles" type="KnowledgeArticleVersion[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.retrieveArticles}" />

    <ui:spinner aura:id="spinner"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.articles}" var="article">
        <p>{!article.Title}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    "retrieveArticles" : function(component, event, helper) {
        var spinner = component.find('spinner');
        var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
        evt.setParams({ isVisible : true });
        evt.fire();

        var action = component.get("c.returnArticles");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                var output = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.articles", output);

                var spinner = component.find('spinner');
                var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
                evt.setParams({ isVisible : false });
                evt.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```